# Roslaunch and Metapackages

Tags: ros, roslaunch, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that [metapackages](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages) should not contain any files except for the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` meant to specify the metapackage, but I'm wondering how I might call a launch file tied to a collection of packages cleanly.

For example, with this package structure:

```
├── catkin_ws
│   └── src
│       └── robot_motion_control
│           ├── robot_motion_control  # Metapackage
│           ├── pilot
│           ├── navigator
│           └── controller
```

If I wanted to run a launch file that groups together the conceptually-related `pilot`, `navigator` and `controller`, I'd want to call something like `roslaunch robot_motion_control do_a_little_dance.launch`, which exists at a higher level of abstraction than any of the three packages.

The problem is that I can't put `.launch` files in a metapackage, and calling something like `roslaunch robot_motion_control_launch do_a_little_dance.launch` feels fairly hacky.

I'd love to run `roslaunch robot_motion_control do_a_little_dance.launch`, but is there a way to architect my metapackage and packages such that I can actually do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270452/roslaunch-and-metapackages/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-08**:
Is `src/robot_motion_control` a metapackage, or just a plain directory that stores the packages in your metapackage into a single location on your FS?

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-09-08**:
`src/robot_motion_control` is the directory that stores the conceptually related packages, including `src/robot_motion_control/robot_motion_control` (the metapackage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the current best practice for these kind of things is to add a package that provides just the launch files that "group [things] together".

Typically those packages are then called `*_bringup` and depend on all the packages that provide the nodes they need for the launch files they provide.

You could take a look at the [wiki/turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot) stack and how it's setup like this.

One thing to note is that such bringup packages can still be installed as a dependency of the overarching metapackage. But seeing as they depend on all the other packages (either directly or transitively), they will essentially be similar to your "metapackage with additional files"-idea.

---

Edit: I think the larger issue is how one would like to provide launch files that do not necessarily depend on specific *nodes* (and thus packages), but actually more on specific *functionality*. The [capabilities](http://wiki.ros.org/capabilities) infrastructure tried to address that, but I haven't seen it used much. ROS2 appears to get something called a *dependency group* ([ros2/design#138](https://github.com/ros2/design/pull/138)), which may make something like a capability based approach a bit easier to implement.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-09-08**:
So the roslaunch call would end up being `roslaunch robot_motion_control_bringup do_a_little_dance.launch`? I'm wondering if the current notion of metapackages is a little too restrictive. I'd love to have launch files and configuration files in the metapackage itself.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-09-08**:
The capabilities project is really interesting - it'd be nice to see if that gets greater use in ros 2.0

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-08**:\

> I'm wondering if the current notion of metapackages is a little too restrictive. I'd love to have launch files and configuration files in the metapackage itself.

well they're really just for grouping *installation artefacts* for deployment purposes. And they do that perfectly, so ..

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-09-08**:
True. I wonder whether `robot_motion_control_meta` would be an appropriate name for the metapackage, then I could house the top-level concepts (launchfiles, configurations, etc.) in `robot_motion_control` as a non-metapackage.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-09**:
That's obviously up to you. I've never seen that though, and I think it's a bit of an awkward name.

Reusing naming conventions allows your users to reuse their experience and to form somewhat of an intuition as to how pkgs are to be used / where they fit. Diverging from that is ok, but should be ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-09**:
.. done after careful consideration of the consequences.